# Why It get out of the while loop with mysql interaction?

Tags: mysql, try-catch

I run this code on Eclipse, I started mysql interactions with java few days ago...

I really don't understand when I execute() a PreparedStatement , It looks like It break out the while loop, maybe It throws an exception and then the try catch breaks, but is there any way to keep the loop?

The comments are on my Language, It just explains what It makes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/base_de_datos_java", "root", "");
        System.out.println("Que quieres hacer:\n1º Crear tabla.\n2º Borrar tabla.\n3º Insertar datos en tabla.\n4º Mostrar tablas de la base de datos.\n9º Salir.");
        String sentenciaUsarBD = "USE base_de_datos_java;";                                         // Sentencia SQL para usar la base de datos.
        PreparedStatement stUBD = (PreparedStatement) conexion.prepareStatement(sentenciaUsarBD);   // Creando la conexion para ejecuta la sentencia
        stUBD.execute();                                                                            // Ejecuntando la sentencia
        int menu = 0;
        while (menu != 9) {
            Scanner scw = new Scanner(System.in);
            menu = scw.nextInt();
            switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                String sqlCrearTabla = "CREATE TABLE ";
                String sentenciaSQLCrear = "CREATE TABLE PRUEBA1(ID INT ,NOMBRE VARCHAR(30));";
                System.out.println("Esta opción por defecto hace : " + sentenciaSQLCrear);
                System.out.println("Deseas usarla? Si o No");
                String menu2 = scw.next();
                if (menu2.equals("Si")) {
                    PreparedStatement st = (PreparedStatement) conexion.prepareStatement(sentenciaSQLCrear);
                    st.execute();
                    // Parece ser que cada vez que se ejecuta una sentencia sin error cierra el programa
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Que tabla desea crear?");
                    String nuevaTabla = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Que columnas desea crear en la tabla: " + nuevaTabla);
                    String nuevaColumna = sc.next();
                    sentenciaSQLCrear = sqlCrearTabla + nuevaTabla + nuevaColumna;
                    System.out.println(sentenciaSQLCrear);
                }
                scw.close();
                break;
            case 2:
                String sentenciaSQLBorrar = "DROP TABLE PRUEBA1;";
                PreparedStatement str = (PreparedStatement) conexion.prepareStatement(sentenciaSQLBorrar);
                str.execute();
                scw.close();
                break;
            case 3:
                String sentenciaSQLInsertar = "INSERT INTO prueba1 VALUES(987654321,'Alex');";
                PreparedStatement stcf = (PreparedStatement) conexion.prepareStatement(sentenciaSQLInsertar);
                stcf.execute();
                scw.close();
                break;
            case 4:
                String sentenciaSQLMostrar = "SHOW TABLES FROM base_de_datos_java;";
                PreparedStatement stm = (PreparedStatement) conexion.prepareStatement(sentenciaSQLMostrar);
                stm.execute();
                ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
                int num3 = 0;
                System.out.println("Tablas de la base de datos");
                while (rs.next() == true) {
                    num3++;
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(num3));
                }
                scw.close();
                break;

            default:

                break;
            }
            System.out.println("\nQue quieres hacer?\n1º Crear tabla.\n2º Borrar tabla.\n3º Insertar datos en tabla.\n4º Mostrar tablas.\n9º Salir.");
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add `e.printStackTrace();` in both the catch blocks and see if it prints anything?

Comment: `null
java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at Inicio.main(Inicio.java:23)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed many code...
Now every preparedStatment are inside a different try catch loop, if It crash It just keep running.
I was closing the scanners, that was the problem in some times.
And It's running well.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, it looks like it fails at the follwing line:

```
menu = scw.nextInt();
```

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) the javadoc of `nextInt` method of Scanner class, this is what it says:

> **Throws:** NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted

So, your code is trying to read an `integer` from `Scanner` but there is nothing left to read, probably because `Scanner` has already read all the input tokens. This is generally the case when you read the tokens with `next()` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()). It reads tokens from `Scanner` but does not `advance` it. If you want to `read` and `advance` the scanner then you need to use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.

P.S. This has nothing to do with your `PrepearedStatement` logic.